# Retrofit enqueue request not return liveData in onResponse method

Tags: android, retrofit, android-livedata

When I use retrofit request to get value from web api, then assign it to liveData. But it always return null before it set value to responseLiveData in onResponse.

```
fun fetchContents(): LiveData<String> {
    val responseLiveData: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
    val flickrRequest: Call<String> = flickrApi.fetchContents()

    flickrRequest.enqueue(object : Callback<String> {

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<String>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to fetch photos", t)
        }

        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<String>,
            response: Response<String>
        ) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Response received")
            responseLiveData.value = response.body()
        }
    })

    return responseLiveData
}

// then assign to the liveData in viewModel
val flickrLiveData: LiveData<String> = FlickrFetchr().fetchContents()
```

This code from the big nerd ranch guide, I find it can not work outOfBox, so I issue this error.

Comment: "But it always return null" -- what exactly do you mean by this? What returns `null`? Note that you could also use the `liveData { }` builder in this case, rather than setting up your own `MutableLiveData`.

Comment: As normal, flickrLiveData will get the value in `responseLiveData.value = response.body()`, but I find it directly return the liveData `return responseLiveData` and no longer execute onResponse method.

Comment: You can add some initial value inside `MutableLiveData` constructor. However you need to observe on liveData if it has any new value using `observe()` method.

Comment: I already observe it on fragment, but the liveData not be changed with this code.